# Add migration path to Mother Meta for per-site metas

Tags: feature-request, migration, meta, per-site-meta, migration-path-request

There are multiple questions, [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s specifically, on per-site metas that affect the whole network. Migrating these questions here would make it seen by a larger community, likely bring it to the attention to the powers that be, and allow it to be answered in a broader sense.

**My proposal:** Just as every site has a default migration path to its per-site meta, every per-site meta should have a default migration path to Mother Meta, AKA Meta.SE.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this should be possible by people other than mods?

Comment: I think users should only be bothered with their own meta site if they have no other accounts. The only thing that seems more useful is duplicate closure against MSE posts  but is IIRC status-declined

Comment: Anything on this, @StackExchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators can already do that when it's appropriate.  My concern with making it a user-accessible option is that too often it's *not* appropriate.

People post feature requests on the metas I'm active on, and usually somebody comments saying "you should ask this on Meta.SE".  Sometimes they even flag asking moderators to do it.  But **it's ok to make feature requests on per-site metas**.  SE monitors those.  The SE team is also smart enough to not make a network-wide change without considering the needs of the network and not just the local site.

It's hard enough sometimes to get people to engage on per-site metas at all.  When they do, I don't want us to send the message "you should have left our site entirely to go ask over there".  It's confusing for newer users; they already left the main site once and now we're sending them even farther away?  For experienced users I'll sometimes suggest that they ask here instead, but we should leave it up to the asker.

Besides, [meta is murder](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/); new users coming here frequently complain about the terrible reception they got because they haven't learned all our rules, customs, and quirks.  I'd *rather* they climb that learning curve on a per-site meta with a known, probably-friendly community.  *Then*, if it makes sense to escalate a request to Meta.SE, the community can help.

Comment: I definitely agree with your last paragraph. It's often the case that a feature supported by a local community may not be supported by the overall SE community at large. This is especially true of some sites, such as MathOverflow. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312478/377214

Comment: Also, users on per-site metas tend to not feel as hurt with downvotes, because there's no rep to lose or gain, whereas here one can lose rep just for making an unpopular suggestion.